# FFmpeg php metadata wrapper

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have two questions about FFmpeg
1. Does FFmpeg Output change with versions (ffmpeg -i)
2. If the output don't change, anyone know a good PHP/Python class that parse FFmpeg Output and get all metadata (Duration, Codec, Audio Biterate, Video Biterate, Width, Height...)
3. if the FFmpeg output change, anyone know a linux tool (cmd line) that get those metadatas without dependence of FFmpeg.

I know that the php-ffmpeg module exist, but it's so old and buggy (wrong duration for example..., can't get $movie->getAudioBitRate() working )

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ffpmpeg-php seems to be your best bet, unless you want to grab/parse ffmpeg's output directly. If you plan on working with remote files (eg. urls vs. local files) then FFmpeg-php will not work with anything but absolute urls (eg. http://example.com/video.mp4 vs. http://example.com/?get_video=234). There might be a cURL option for accomplishing this but I've yet to come across anything stable.

Comment: ffmpeg-php is too old, and i had a lot of bugs, it dosn't recognize all video formats.

Comment: I Tested phpvideotoolkit http://code.google.com/p/phpvideotoolkit/
it works fine, but require the installation of Ffmpeg on the server.

Comment: ffmpeg-php5 also requires installation. It's a php extension and needs to be compiled on your server. If you are using a host that gives you shell access, then you're probably on a linux box. If you've got root privileges you can simply type "sudo apt-get install php5-ffmpeg" and all the work is done for you :) Is it buggy? Hmm.. well I wouldn't know. I'm writing a class that extracts metadata from remote media files. So far it's been pretty reliable with mp4, flv, mov, and some other formats. Make sure you have the latest version of FFmpeg, and remember, FFmpeg-PHP5 is just a wrapper!